# Fourier transform of a function of $\cos(\omega \cdot t)$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I need your help. 
Suppose I have a function $V(x)$. 
Now suppose I vary it with time as $W(x,t) = V(x+\cos(\omega \cdot t)$.
I need to find out What is the fourier transform of $W(x,t)$ with respect to $t$.
In other words I need to derive $\int{W(x,t)e^{i\omega t}dt} = \int{V(x+\cos(\omega\cdot t))e^{i\omega t}dt}$

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts and have tried some things so responders don't rehash those items? Regards

Comment: Since $\cos(\omega t)$ is periodic in $t$, so is $W(x,t)$. Namely $W(x,t + 2\pi / \omega) = W(x,t)$. This means that function will **not** be absolutely integrable on the line, as a function of $t$, and the Fourier integral will fail to converge in general. On the other hand, since $W(x,t)$ is periodic with period $2\pi / \omega$, perhaps you want to instead consider its corresponding Fourier series?

Answer (score 2):

Just a possible idea:

If V(x) is a periodic function in x with period $\tau$, take the exponential Fourier series of $V(x)$:

$V(x) = \sum_{n =-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{inx}$

where $c_n = \frac{1}{\tau}\int_0^\tau V(x)e^{-inx}$

and plug in $W(x, t) = V(x + \cos(\omega t))$

$W(x,t) = \sum_{n =-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{inx}e^{i n\cos(\omega t)}$

Use the [general form of the Jacobi-Anger expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi-anger_expansion) to get:

$W(x,t) = \sum_{n =-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{inx}\sum_{k =-\infty}^{\infty}i^kJ_k(n)e^{ik\omega t}$

or in terms of cosines:

$W(x,t) = \sum_{n =-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{inx}(J_0(n) + 2\sum_{k =-\infty}^{\infty}i^kJ_k(n)\cos(k \omega t)) = $

$\sum_{n =-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{inx}J_0(n) + 2\sum_{n =-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{inx}\sum_{k =-\infty}^{\infty}i^kJ_k(n)\cos(k \omega t)$

Where $J_k$ is the Bessel function of order k.

Fourier transform both sides:

$\mathscr{F} W(x,t) = \sum_{n =-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{inx}J_0(n)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1 e^{-2\pi i s t}dt + 2\sum_{n =-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{inx}\sum_{k =-\infty}^{\infty}i^kJ_k(n)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(k \omega t)e^{-2\pi i s t}dt =$

$\sum_{n =-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{inx}J_0(n)\delta(s) + \sum_{n =-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{k =-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{inx}i^kJ_k(n)((\delta(s - k f_0) + \delta(s + k f_0))$

Where $\omega = 2 \pi f_0.$

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Birtex!
however I fail to understand it..
$V(x)$ is not periodic with time it is a function of $x$ (not $t$) I define a new function $W(x,t) = V(x+\cos(\omega\cdot t))$ and I want to find the fourier transform of $W(x,t)$.
I do not understand what do you mean by $V(W(x,t))$...

Thanks again!

Comment: @Grisha Sorry, I did this when I was tired and made some mistakes.  I have edited my answer.